# I need to manually parition a HD to install

Tags: 11.04, partitioning, installation

I have a 50 gb partition that needs to be manually paritioned, how should I do this?

I need to know what partitions to make, and what size they should be.

Comment: Why does it need to be manually partitioned? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For whatever reason it won't give me the option to do a side by side install. I just want to get it installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete The partition and Make a Partition form the Unpartitioned Space!

**On Maverick Meerkat:**

On the partitioning screen **Click Specify Partitions Manually(advanced)** Just delete the partition and then Select the Unallocated Space and click 'New' Now just enter the size and the other thing you would enter at the install menus.

'/' should be 8GB at least, that is what I recommend.

Hope I was a good help :)

Comment: Sorry I will fix my questions to be more specific, I guess what I was looking for was recommendations on what size to make the various partitions for Ubuntu, and what all is required.. such as root/home or whatever

Comment: You would need To have at a max a '/' partition of 8GB. Then Make the rest '/home' With using a separate partition on home you can keep all your settings and don't worry about loosing things when You upgrade :).

Comment: so if 8 is the max, what is the min?

Comment: Oh sorry, I think 6 is the Min, but you are pushing it. I recommend 8 GB. I will fix the post :)

Comment: It just seems that 8gb is a lot of space to have for the root drive... but I guess that is where the OS and all the apps go, so maybe it isn't

Comment: Yup, All the apps go in /opt and /etc and '/' is under that zone. So It makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to setup for a dual boot system, you'll need to first shrink the Windows partition. You can do that with the [Gparted partition editor](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) if the Ubuntu installer isn't working for you. After booting the Gparted CD, select the Windows partition, select Resize, then move the slider to the size you want. Then just click Apply and wait.

If you don't want to dual boot, you can just clear all partitions using the Ubuntu installer or Gparted.

To partition the drive for Linux, you should create at minimum a swap partition and a root (/) partition. You could also create a separate /boot and /home partitions for safety and flexibility later down the road.

/boot should be about 100 MB.
swap should be equal to your amount of memory.
/home is up to you, but should fairly large.
/ is everything that's left over.